# What Are Logarithms?

Tags: mathematics

I'm just starting out and have a limited area of mathematic study and have no idea how to do logarithms. I know that they're involved in physics and want to progress. Could someone help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about physics and I consider it of too low quality to migrate it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Answer (score 2):

As you can express all logarithms in terms of the natural logarithm, this is the only one to worry about.

The natural logarithm $\ln(x)$ is the inverse of the exponential function $e^{x}$.

There are many different perspectives you can have here, but to mention just one: If you think of the exponential function as converting additions into multiplications, the logarithm (inverse function) transforms multiplications into additions. I'm not a historian, but I guess this is why people found the logarithm to be useful in the first place: additions are easy, multiplications are difficult... Technically speaking, the exponential and logarithm are group homomorphisms between the real numbers either taken with multiplication or addition as the group operation.

There is a more general notion of exponential functions and logarithms in the context of Lie group theory, arguably the real line (with multiplication) being just the most simple example of a Lie group.

Comment: You have not answered the question, "What are logarithms?"  Nor should you answer it.  The OP has showed no effort to find the answer for himself.

Comment: I know that this questions like these go against the rules of stackexchange. But sperber's answer actually gave me a new perspective on logarithms. This is the kind of stuff that you don't find in textbooks and the stuff you hope to learn from other individuals through the exchange of ideas.

Comment: I actually have tried to figure this out but none of the places I have tried to look make sense to me

Comment: @MatthewMorrissette: I figured that out, so I gave a short answer to hopefully open up new lines of thought. I find it depressing, if not horrifying, to see people react to such questions for a wider perspective by labeling it as "off-topic". Furthermore, essentially just stating that an answer in itself is a bad thing gets upvotes! Seriously? I have seen this kind of behaviour on the physics forum more than once, and I'm only around for a short time. Is the moderation broken if it allows for such rudeness and stupidity? Why be so shortsighted? Let there be stupid questions!

Comment: @sperber In my opinion, as long as you actually have a point to your question, it cannot be "stupid". a questions can be simple, but not stupid.

Comment: @MatthewMorrissette: To me, the notion of a "stupid question" has a more light-hearted meaning, like in "let's just be silly and/or uncomfortable for a moment, and see where we get this way". Stupid questions are not necessarily stupid (they very rarely are), and certainly need not be simple ;).

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is - count zeros. 1000 is 10^3, so 3 is its log (base 10). Similarly, the log of 100 is 2. So what number has log 2.5? 316!

Logs are nifty because you can multiply numbers by adding their logs.
Slide rules are based on this.

Comment: thanks this is actually helpful! I don't know why someone said it was "off-topic" but thanks

Comment: @MatthewMorrissette: Well, I was a professor once, so I don't mind answering elementary questions, but that makes me an outlier. There are people on this site who can answer questions at the cutting edge of physics. The more physics you learn, the more you will see how great this website is.

Comment: Forgive me: I think you should specify "assuming you mean logarithm to base $10$".